# $\mathbb{C} = \bigcup_{\omega \in L } (\omega + \mathcal{F})$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a fundamental parallelogramm of the lattice  $L$. Show 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{C} = \bigcup_{\omega \in L } (\omega + \mathcal{F}) \, .
\end{align*}

In the solutions they wrote *The claim follows directly from the well-known fact that for any real $n$ $x$ there exists an integer $n$ with $0 ≤ x − n ≤ 1.$*

How can one write the proof formally?

The definition of the fundamental parallelogramm is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}(\omega_1,\omega_2) = \{ t_1 \omega_1 + t_2 \omega_2 ; 0 \leq t_1,t_2 \leq 1 \}
\end{align*}

Comment: This is the very definition of a lattice or of its fundamental parallelogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof.** Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then :
\begin{align*}
z= s_1 \omega_1 + s_2 \omega_2 , \quad s_1, s_2 \in [0,1)
\end{align*}
For any real number $s_1,s_2$ there exists $n_1,n_2$ so that
\begin{align*}
0\leq s_1 - n_1 \leq 1, \quad 0 \leq s_2 - n_2 \leq 1
\end{align*}
and then we can write
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{s_1 \omega_1 + s_2 \omega_2}_{=z\in \mathbb{C}} = (s_1 -n_1 ) \omega_1 + (s_2-n_2) \omega_2 
\end{align*}
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Every complex number can be written in the form
$$
z = t_{1}\omega_{1} + t_{2}\omega_{2}
$$
for some real $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$. Decompose these (uniquely) as in your hint, into an integer plus a real number in $[0, 1)$.